# dynamic programming approach in a non-specific direction calculation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [Ball Removal problem on topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12157), pasting the problem statement here as login is required to access this link.

---

> Problem Statement
>
> You have N balls, where N is odd. The balls are numbered from 0 to N-1. In that order, they are arranged into a row going from the left to the right.
>
> In addition to the number, each ball has either the word "left" or the word "right" written on it. For simplicity, we will use the character '<' instead of "left", and the character '>' instead of "right". You are given the labels on all balls as the String label. For each i, character i of label represents the word on ball i.
>
> You will now repeat the following procedure:
>
> - Choose a ball that is not at either end of the row of balls.
> - If the chosen ball has the label '<', remove the chosen ball and also the ball immediately to the left of it. Otherwise, remove the chosen ball and also the ball to the right of it.
> - Without reordering the remaining balls, push them together to get rid of the gap created in the previous step.
>
> The process ends when only one ball remains in the row. That ball is called the survivor. Note that the numbers on the balls do not change during the process.
>
> Find all possible survivors. Your method must return a String containing exactly N characters. If ball i can be the survivor, character i of the return value must be 'o' (lowercase oh). Otherwise, the corresponding character must be '.' (a period).
>
> Constraints
>
> - label will contain between 3 and 49 characters, inclusive.
> - label will contain an odd number of characters.
> - Each character of label will be either '>' or '<'.
>
> Examples
>   "<<>"
>   Returns: "..o"
>
> Initially, you have three balls. Since you cannot choose balls at the ends of the row, you have to choose ball 1. As its label is '<', you remove balls 0 and 1. Hence the only possible survivor is ball 2.
>   1)
>   ">>><<"
>   Returns: "o...o"
>
> If you choose ball 2 or ball 3 first, you have to choose ball 1 next, and the survivor will be ball 0. If you choose ball 1 first, you have to choose ball 3 next, and the survivor will be ball 4.
>
> 2)
>   "<<><<" 
>   Returns: "....o"
>
> 3)
>   "<><<><>"
>   Returns: "o.....o"
>
> 4)
>   ">>><<<>>>>><<<>"
>   Returns: "o.....o.o.....o"

---

I am thinking of a dynamic programming approach to this problem, I am thinking of having an boolean array to mark which of the characters have been deleted and then find which is next left and next right but that makes the approach quite inefficient and I have to write a recursive method. For implementing a dynamic programming approach I need to maintain a state. But I am not able to figure out what I should keep as state, in my thinking a state is combination of both current string and current index, but maintaining a string for state doesn't seem correct to me.

One more problem I am facing is that in this case I don't have a particular direction if I change direction result changes also if I move left to right I might need to move right to left also.
Please help me in finding a proper approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state can be boolean - `DP[left][right][isLeftBoundary][isRightBoundary]`.

This means if the substring starting at `left` and finishing at `right` can be fully eliminated.

`isLeftBoundary` is just a boolean flag if the `left` symbol is the leftmost of the string.

`isRightBoundary` is just a boolean flag if the `right` symbol is the rightmost of the string.

if `DP[0][i - 1][1][0]` and `DP[i + 1][N][0][1]` are `true`, it means the ball at position `i` can remain.

```
    int canDelete(int l, int r, int st, int en)
    {
        if (l > r) return 1; //we succeeded in removing the whole string

        if (DP[l][r][st][en] != -1)
           return DP[l][r][st][en];

        int ans = 0;

        //i is the last removed ball, which will eliminate the whole string[l, r]
        for (int i = l + st; i <= r - en; i++) 
        {
            if (inp[i] == '<') //it will remove a ball to the left, but which one?
            {
                for (int j = l; j < i; j++) //ball i will remove ball j
                {       
                     if (canDelete(l, j - 1, st, 0) 
                      && canDelete(j + 1, i - 1, 0, 0) 
                      && canDelete(i + 1, r, 0, en))
                         ans = 1;       
                }
            }
            else
            if (inp[i] == '>') //it will remove a ball to the right, but which one?
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= r; j++) //ball i will remove ball j
                {       
                     if (canDelete(l, i - 1, st, 0) 
                      && canDelete(i + 1, j - 1, 0, 0) 
                      && canDelete(j + 1, r, 0, en))
                         ans = 1;       
                }       
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to get how do you account for deletions in the string? Even if locations remain the same string is not the same so DP table should differentiate between the two cases?

Comment: See my edit. You basically look at the problem backwards. You try every ball to be the last removed ball.

Comment: When you choose the final removal pair(i, j) you divide the remaining string in three parts - left, middle and right. The three parts are just the same independent subproblems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and explanation, I am still confused about 1. Why are you iterating over which ball to delete, when its given in statement that you have to delete the next left/right? 2. Why are we working backwards and doing memoization not dynamic programming? 3. When we find ans=1 shouldn't we break out of the for loop? 4. What is use of knowing isleft/rightboundary in DP table?

Comment: 1. This is the essential thing to understand here. If you simulate the game from the beginning, you can't break it properly into independent subproblems. Because after you remove the current ball and the ball directly to the left, the two remaining parts are NOT independent. Think about it. 2. Memoization is recursive dynamic programming. The algorithm is still the same. 3. Yes, when ans = 1, you can break the loop. My code works too, because ans cannot be 0, after it becomes 1. It is just I do some unnecessary loops more.

Comment: 4. isLeftBoundary tells you, if you can remove the leftmost ball. If it is at the boundary, you can't remove it. The idea for isRightBoundary is the same.

Comment: We can go to StackOverflow chat if you want a detailed explanation. I will give you real examples.

Comment: Thanks a ton. yes that will be really very helpful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20339/discussion-between-petar-minchev-and-gaurav)